# referencing report fields in Birt

Tags: birt

My birt report has three tables, with different datasets/SQL sources, of course
In the first, there is an aggregate field (SUM), tha is call "total_materias_primas"
In the second, there is another aggregate, called "total_aditivos"
And finally, in the third I need to aggregate(SUM) by one field, and then sum again my lastest "total_materias_primas" and "total_aditivos"
I don't know how can be "total_materias_primas" and "total_aditivos" referenced in the third table/dataset

Thanks

```
report["total_materias_primas"] /* no result */
record["total_materias_primas"] /* no result */
row["total_materias_primas"]    /* no result */
```

No code

Answer (score 0):

So you want to compute a total summary of tables 1-3, right?

You could use a structure like this:

```
Table 1 (DS 1)
  Header Row
  Detail Row
  Footer Row (all columns merged)
    Table 2 (DS 2)
      Header Row
      Detail Row
      Footer Row (all columns merged)
        Table 3 (DS 3)
          Header Row
          Detail Row
          Footer Row
            Cell
              Label "Total 1-3"
                Data "Total_1_3"
```

Say, your total for table 3 is called "total3".
Add a binding for table 3 called "Total_1_3" with the expression

```
row["total3"] + row._outer["total_aditivos"] + row._outer._outer["total_materias_primas"].
```

In a nested table/list structure, row._outer accessing the row of the outer data set.
It is typically used in master-detail reports.

In your case, it's not actually a master-detail-report, but we use the idea.

Another solution without nesting the tables would use report variables.
Set three report variables in the footers of table 1 - 3, then use them below.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I think I can continue with your help